# Manusmriti with commentary of Kulluka Bhatta

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, reference-request

I am looking for translated versions (English/Hindi) of Manusmriti with commentary of Kulluka Bhatta online .

Comment: Have only read the Sanskrit version: https://archive.org/details/manusmritinirnaysaharpress_968_O/mode/2up

Comment: Here is a link to the hard copy. https://www.abebooks.co.uk/first-edition/Manusmrti-Text-kulluka-Bhatta-Commentary-English-Translation/17264299811/bd